# Android Web View Get Stretched On Layout Width Change

Tags: android, android-webview

I am having hard time while rendering webview inside my native app, i have pasted some screen shots below which shows how webview is behaving every time width is getting changed.

Also i am using drawer menu which makes webview move towards right everytime i open menu drawer

SCREEN SHOT WHEN WEBVIEW IS LOADED

[image]

Till now it seems to be fine but now when i open and close the drawer menu it does not change it's width back to 100% and remains at 50%

AFTER OPENING AND CLOSING DRAWER MENU

[image]

It also blurs the webview when i open the drawer menu

SCREEN SHOT WHEN DRAWER MENU IS OPEN

[image]

I have also tried some different settings of webview but none of them worked, also here goes my webview java code

JAVA CODE

```
                 mWebView = (WebView) findViewById( R.id.webView1 );
             mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
             mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
             mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
             // Load URL
             mWebView.loadUrl(requestUrl);
```

Comment: Is this on a physical device? Or an emulator?

Comment: Which library are you using for the drawer/side navigation menu?

Comment: Here goes the link https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer , is it due to the drawer menu ???  because it works fine with my native android activities

Comment: I would try to narrow down the problem. Try using the Layout Hierarchy Viewer to figure out what the actual dimensions of the WebView are. If it's in a fragment, make sure it's being attached to the activity correctly.

Comment: But yeah, especially the stretching is very weird.

Comment: It seems that it may be related to android-menudrawer as [this issue seems somewhat similar](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/issues/72).

Comment: okay will try that, also is it possible to get the same result using tablelayout , because i never wanted to use webview, the url to the webview goes here http://mobile.unext.in/androidDBU/user_scores.php?key=androidbaby&username=ankitgupta

Comment: It seems [the library also has difficulties with SurfaceViews](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/issues/24), likely due to hardware acceleration. Perhaps you can try disabling it through [`android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in your manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) to see if that is the cause.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23986/discussion-between-paul-lammertsma-and-aman-virk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Following our discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23986/discussion-between-paul-lammertsma-and-aman-virk), it seems that the problem is related to the `android-menudrawer` library. Specifically, hardware accelerated widgets don't appear correctly after the drawer is opened, as also described by [this issue concerning MapView v2](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/issues/48#issuecomment-11875958).

The most basic solution is disabling hardware acceleration by setting  `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in your manifest, but I would encourage you to explore a better solution, such as [this one](https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer/issues/48#issuecomment-11875958) suggested by the author of the above issue:

> I discovered an easy hack.
>
> You simply create RelativeLayout with content placeholder and
> transparent overlay that always visible. Every click events inside
> content works ok and bug also disappears:
>
> ```
> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent">
>
>     <FrameLayout
>             android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent" />
>
>     <FrameLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
>
> </RelativeLayout>
> ```

Comment: The thread showing the hack does not seems to be working but as you mentioned setting the hardwareAccelerated to false seems to be promising as it works all the way fine... THANKS